# Diff between <head id="Head1" runat="server"> and <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent">

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Looking for an better understanding of how an mvc project should define javascript and css includes. I'm working with sample code where includes are defined like:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />Affiliate Checkout</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
.
.
.
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

I'm reading that to be that _all pages looking at this MasterPage will get jquery and jqueryUI and, additionally, each page will have the opportunity to add head elements thankx to the content placeholder HeadContent tag.

The specific problem i'm troubleshooting is an instance where my rendered page is not including the 'prama no-cache' tag - as you see, it's defined in the upper level header section. Other .js and .css elements are making it into the rendered page so it very confusing to see that the no-cache tag isn't.

When execute a 'View Generated Source' - the 'charset' is present the 'no-cache' is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be because the pragma meta tag is not closed properly?